# Nginx revers proxy config showing 404 not found

Tags: nginx

i am going to set a location `/attendance` and want to make all the requests could redirect to `https://example.me.com`

follows the nginx.conf i've set

```
// nginx.conf

// upstream
upstream attendance {
  server https://example.me.com/
}

// location
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        ...
        location /attendance {
            proxy_pass http://attendance/;
        }
}
```

which shows 404 and how to deal with it?

example:

working api is : `https://example.me.com/xx/xxx`
and i am going to have a post request like:

`http://my.nginx.server.ip/attendance/xx/xxx`

Comment: sorry , mine trying one is `server` instead of `proxy_pass`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `upstream` block and pass the requests directly to your backend:

```
// nginx.conf

server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        ...
        location /attendance/ {
            proxy_pass http://my.example.com/;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reverse proxy will forward requests to `http://upstream/attendance/...`, If you want forward without `/attendance` sub-directory, add this rewrite rule inside location block.

`rewrite /attendance(.*) $1 break;`